# How can I edit the resources in an executable using C++?

Tags: c++, resources, executable, portable-executable

I need a way to edit the resources (A String Table, to be exact) of a compiled executable and I need to do it in C++.

Can anybody offer any guidance/sample code on how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Um. If you're asking what I think you're asking then its not possible.

Comment: [Resource hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) ... not sure if it supports modifying string tables though.

Comment: Resource Hacker does the job, but I need to do it inside my own application.

Comment: @user1661022 Then all you need now is a tool to decompile Resource Hacker :)

Comment: Is the resource table skipped as part of Authenticode signature validation? I didn't think it was. I only ask because if he's planning on doing this on libs that are already signed by someone else and he hasn't access to the signing cert *and* Authenticode checks resource tables as part of its digest-calc, then, in a word, you're bent, dude.

Comment: As a side note, you can open exe/dll files in visual studio and it will show the resource data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with `LoadLibrary()` that and load an executable(the one you want to edit)
Then `FindResource()` and `UpdateResource()` as necessary.

Read all about it here:

[PE format Resource Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468902(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Linux or OS X there's always the "strings" command that will print out all of the static strings in the executable.  Combine that with something like "objdump" and some knowledge with a hex editor you may be able to cobble something together.

Comment: yo bro, he is talking about PE = windows :P

Comment: The original question didn't specify an OS, but good information anyways :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that is even possible, once you have a compiled executable & it's just machine code, there isn't really a specific way to understand how to interpret it (and therefore find/edit the resources you're looking for)...i.e. once you have just the executable, you can't for sure know whether a word is an instruction in assembly or just a word representing a number, label, etc in assembly...

As far as I know.

Comment: What you're telling here is far from reality. Of course also compiled executable files (and resources embedded with them) have a well defined format that can be investigated and manipulated as long you know the structure.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right - provided that you know the structure. But is it possible to just take an arbitrary executable and parse it correctly? I was under the impression that parsing an arbitrary executable would be really difficult because it depends on the compiler/how the compiler was used/what architecture it's compiled for.

Comment: It requires lots of structures and parsing, but it's an absolutely solvable problem. For instance, [pev](https://github.com/merces/pev) is a cross-platform PE file analysis toolkit, and it parses nearly all PE format. It doesn't allow editing though, but it's half-way there for anyone with advanced C skills (assuming the Windows API is not always at your disposal, as is the case for pev).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the good old reference and source code of [PeDump](http://www.wheaty.net/pedump.zip) of Matt Pietrek. He does handle (read-only) the resources of PE files in C++. Maybe it will inspires you to solve your problem...

Comment: I learned a lot from Matt Pietrek when I started with the implementation of PeStudio (http://www.winitor.com)